# How to change character set to UTF8 in visual basic express 2013?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013

I am writing a clinic program using visual basic express 2013, I wrote the whole program then I noticed that when inserting patients in Arabic language my sql database showing ??????? in every field, people told me I have to change my database character set to UTF8 but I don't know how, any solution would be great.

note: I tried changing table definition with collate Arabic but no luck.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In .net all strings are in Unicode which supports all character sets. What I would guess is missing is to set your table columns to nvarchar.

Regards

Av

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, yes I changed them but nothing happened still when inserting keeps showing ???????????

Comment: Yes, they probably just need to use `nvarchar` and quote their string literals correctly (`N'...'` rather than `'...'`).